# Should we start swapping server session management for the new HTML5 standard session storage?

Tags: php, html, session

Given the flexibility of HTML5 to better manage sessions, should we start using it in place of server management (eg, PHP)? What possible pros & cons can it have?

Lets ignore the fact HTML5 isn't complete yet; talking about when it's fully implemented.

While the question can be opinion based, I'd like to see facts please.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you are doing.  There are some things that simply *must* be handled server-side, while situations that only affect the client-side implementation may benefit from HTML5.

I'll precaution, however, that even when HTML5 gets finalized, this does not mean every user on your site will suddenly have flawless HTML5 ability that you can just "turn on".  Although HTML5-able users may benefit from it's features, it's good programming practice to have a fallback, at least until reasonable statistics show that almost everyone is using HTML5-supported browsers.

Anyway, here are some examples of things that can be safely handled in HTML5 sessions

- Unsubmitted form data (eg, if a user starts filling out a form, then closes the page, then comes back to the page at a later time)
- Analytics data (Google and other providers may benefit from using HTML5 to identify unique visitors and their actions on a website)
- Identifying whether a user has been to the site before, or has performed an action (some sites show a popup the first time the user comes to a site, or may want to show a popup when a new feature is released, but want this to never show again after they close it)

And here are some things that *should* be handled server-side:

- logins. While some people may disagree with me here, I think it's best for the server check whether a user is logged in on every request.  This prevents attacks where a user modifies their HTML5 data to a sessionid they got through phishing (or guessing).  I always use PHP and (usually) MySQL to keep track of logins.  If this is not checked by and controlled by the server, it's a security risk.
- dynamic user content.  Whenever I need to deliver anything client-specific, I make sure control is held by the server to prevent attacks from the client (which, IMHO, should never be trusted because they can be modified)

This may not be "fact-based", but I think it's pretty logical: anything you can do entirely client side could probably benefit from HTML5 (that's why HTML5 was created, btw).  But anything that needs security or server-access should be handled by server-based sessions.

Comment: Totally agree with you. I feel like when you start using client-side tools for security purposes you compromise that security. And what I meant by fact-based was more what you did: back it up with logical/factual claims.